# Is it safe to use std::vector<char> as storage for heterogeneous records?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have a need to work with records made of a series of POD elements.
The types of those elements are found at run time before a series of those records are processed. Ideally the storage for the records would hold the elements contiguously so the storage can be directly populated or output with system IO calls.

Given the following simplified example code:

```
template<typename T>
struct ElementAccessor {
    ElementAccessor(int offset)
    :
        _offset(offset)
    {}

    T &operator () (void * data)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T &>(
           *reinterpret_cast<char *>(data) + _offset);
    }
    int _offset;
};

ElementAccessor<float> fEl(0);
ElementAccessor<int> iEl(sizeof(float));
```

I am looking for a valid and convenient way to store the records?

I have considered the following methods:

**`vector<int>`**

Using a `vector<int>` seems convenient:

```
std::vector<int> intData(2);
iEl(intData.data()) = 42;
fEl(intData.data()) = 12.4f; //< Uh-oh,  undefined behaviour, maybe zero initialization could be reordered after this point!
```

but would violate the strict-aliasing rule.

**`Raw allocated memory`**

I believe the below is valid code, but is inconvenient as memory management is manual:

```
void *voidData(operator new(2 * sizeof(int)));
iEl(voidData) = 42;
fEl(voidData) = 12.4f;
...
operator delete(voidData);
```

**`std::vector<char>`**

How about using a `std::vector<char>`:

```
std::vector<char> charData(2 * sizeof(int));
iEl(charData.data()) = 42;
fEl(charData.data()) = 12.4f;
```

It is convenient in that the `std::vector` nicely handles the memory management.
But is it valid?

Comment: You might want to reconsider your design, or your choice of a homogeneous container. There are ways around it, with e.g. [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), but I wouldn't really recommend it as it makes your code hard to understand, read and maintain.

Comment: The size of a record will change depending on the template type. Consider using a base class interface and storing only derived classes instances.

Comment: I didn't mention, but I'm keen to store the element contiguously in memory as that way they can be used directly as the buffers for efficient IO operations. 
@Someprogrammerdude I think with std::variant the data layout would end up with padding around the smaller elements.

Comment: I'm not sure if assigning to type-punned char buffer is well-defined in the first place...

Comment: "I believe the below is valid code" - it has mismatched parentheses

Comment: It is UB to alias `char` as `int`, and also UB to "alias" object-liess storage as `int` or anything else. You can create objects in the storage by using placement-new

Comment: While `std::vector` seems to store objects, what it really have is an array (or rather a pointer to some dynamically allocated memory) or bytes. You can't access this byte-array yourself, but you can use it as inspiration to make your own heterogeneous "vector-like" class. Then you can store data anywhere in your "array of bytes" any way you like with the help of placement-new. You of course needs some way to keep track of what data is stored where, so you don't try to access an `int` when a `double` is actually stored in parts of the location.

Comment: And an important note about a byte-array solution: Not all platforms support unaligned access to all data. You *need* to have padding if you want to be cross-platform, and you of course need to keep track of where that padding is (or rather where the actual elements are).

Answer (score 1):

None of your proposed options are correct according to the Standard, due to violations of strict-aliasing and alignment.

What you can do is `memcpy` between an arbitrary offset into the buffer and a type of your choosing.  But no operating on the data "in place".